# Are silent Expo push-notifications possible?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a critical requirement for my app where I need to silently process PUSH notifications in both Android and IOS.

I've already made a prototype that receives the notifications, but I didn't find a way to avoid the prompt and the sound.

Is that even possible using Expo? should I use pure react-native instead?

Comment: We don't support this yet, but we expect to at some point in the future.

Comment: On iOS you can use the undocumented (non-public API) `_contentAvailable: 1` field.

Comment: If it is not supported yet, what do you recommend me to achieve this in react native?

Comment: I was just looking for this possibility.  But the contentAvailable: 1 field is now accessible.  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: having a "content-available" field strongly implies that it should support background updates. Until recently, Apple recommended not having ANY OTHER field if that field was set, and would not guarantee any other field making it across. The flag was strictly to trigger background downloads that had to complete processing in 30 seconds. Now you can add other fields, but the purpose is still unchanged.

Comment: Does Expo now support silent notification, I did go through the documentation but I did not find anything around it.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to send a "silent" notification to update the badge count on our iOS and Android apps. The solution I found is to send a notification throw the "https://expo.dev/notifications" and did not provide "title" and "message" content, only provided the "badge count" info.

Works like a charm for us.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: i also used this trick. just send an empty title and message. on android, notification will be silent

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is in Expo Go the `Notifications.setNotification()` does not fire when the app is backgrounded.  Instead the default notification handler which shows the content appears.

You can send a "silent" notification by removing the `title` and `body` from the message being sent to Expo Push Notifications.  Then use the `data` to provide the details for the notifications.

Here is a `notification-handler.ts` that would add as a side-effect the background notification handler.

```js
import * as Notifications from "expo-notifications";
import * as TaskManager from "expo-task-manager";

// This is a custom type as the `data` sent is unknown, so if
// you know what to expect you can utilize TypeScript to provide
// you with a cleaner data mapping.
type MyNotificationData = {
  body: Record<string, string>,
  experienceId: string,
  projectId: string,
}

const BACKGROUND_NOTIFICATION_TASK = "BACKGROUND-NOTIFICATION-TASK";

TaskManager.defineTask(
  BACKGROUND_NOTIFICATION_TASK,
  async ({ data, error, executionInfo }) => {
    const notificationData = data as NotificationData;
    // do your thing

    // make your own notification
    await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
      content: {
        title: notificationData.body.titleText,
        body: notificationData.body.bodyText
      },
      trigger: null, // show the notification immediately
    });
  },
);

Notifications.registerTaskAsync(BACKGROUND_NOTIFICATION_TASK);
```

For this to work in iOS you also need to add to the `app.json` the `UIBackgroundModes` array with `remote-notification` e.g. with background fetch support as well

```json
"ios": {
  "infoPlist": {
    "UIBackgroundModes": ["remote-notification", "fetch"]
  }
}
```

This answer combines information from

- https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#handle-incoming-notifications-when-the-app-is-1
- https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#schedulenotificationasyncrequest
- https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#background-notifications

In addition for this to work with iOS you need to add `_contentAvailable: true` to the payload.  e.g.

```bash
curl -X POST https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   -d '{
    "to":"ExponentPushToken[mytoken]",
    "_contentAvailable":true,
    "data":{"testing":123}
   }'
```